# Craft CMS and LiteSpeed (403 error on login)

Tags: error, login

When trying to login to the administration section on a server running [LiteSpeed](https://www.litespeedtech.com), half the time LiteSpeed triggers a 403 Forbidden message and locks that computer out of the entire server Craft is running on. I'm assuming Craft is doing something that LiteSpeed deems as suspicious but I have no idea what that could be.

I'm currently trying to get access to the logs but the host is taking it's sweet time. In an ideal world I would just find another host but in this situation that's just not feasible. I'm pulling my hair out trying to get this to work, and I found love with Craft that I don't want to deny.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be so grateful!

Comment: Don't have experience with LightSpeed, but are you sure it's not mod_security or Suhosin?

Comment: Suhosin is not enabled, and I have no idea if mod_security is or isn't (don't have a lot of control over the server), but I tried disabling it through .htaccess and I think that might've done the trick. I'll update this at the end of the day after seeing if it continues to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out mod_security was the culprit, so disabling it got Craft working.